# NodeJS spawn ffmpeg thumb %t in filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, ffmpeg

I'm creating screenshots at 15 fps with this NodeJS code:

```
var spawn   = require('child_process').spawn;
var args    = ['-ss', '00:00:07.86', '-i', 'filename.mp4', '-vf', 'fps=15', '/out%d.png'];
var ffmpeg  = spawn('ffmpeg', args);
```

This works fine, but I want the time stamp of each screenshot in the filename.

from FFMPEG docs:

> %t is expanded to a timestamp

But putting `... ,'/out%t.png']` fails and prints:

```
grep stderr: [image2 @ 0x7f828c802c00] Could not get frame filename 
number 2 from pattern '/Users/***/projects/out%t.png' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
...
grep stderr: Conversion failed!

child process exited with code 1
```

So that doesn't look like the way to go.

How do i get the timestamp for each screenshot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `%d` is the only param that you can use in this case.
You can use `%t` for report filename when using the `-report` param, but not for video frames.

Knowing video length, start time (00:00:07.86) and FPS (15) you can match frame numbers from filenames with frame timestamps, and rename all the files after `ffmpeg` finish extracting frames. It's an ugly workaround for sure, but it's the only thing I can come up with...

Answer (score 0):

According to poohitan comment, I end up building a workaround correlating the generated frame number, start time and fps to actual frame timestamp.

```
Video.frameToSec = function(imageName, start, fps) {
//    imageName => out209.png
    start = start || 0;

    var thenum = imageName.match(/\d/g);
    thenum = thenum.join('');

    var fps_sec = 1 / fps;

    var sec = thenum * fps_sec - fps_sec / 2 + start;

    return {imageName:imageName,sec:sec};
}
```

Too bad ffmpeg doesnt have a built in attribute because when creating screenshot the timestamp is important.

Anyway thanks for the help!